# Log4j2 Issue with RollingFileAppender rotation with AsyncLogger

Tags: log4j2

I have this log4j.xml configuration file: http://www.grupoventus.com/download/log4j.xml

There is an async logger called LOGGER_ACCESS that is using a RollingFileAppender named ACCESS_LOG.

Yesterday I sent an stress test against our application, about 500 simultaneous requests. Every request appends a new line to the current log.

At 00:00 log file was rotated, and now there are two logs (as expected): vproxy_acccess.2015-04-16 (the older) and vproxy_access (the current from today, day 17).

But if we take a look to the old log file, we see this. Below the last two lines of my log:

1,1429221599904,A,56,A,66,A,,190,A,S,5,S,2359,0000,2359,0,N,188.165.133.226,gzip,86,456,93,89,error.0011,**2015-04-16 23:59:59**

1,1429221599999,A,56,A,66,A,,190,A,S,5,S,2359,0000,2359,300000,S,,gzip,66342,456,1064,0,ok,**2015-04-17 00:00:00**

The first request from 2015-04-17 has been included into the log from day 16. Just the first one, the rest have been correctly appended to the vproxy_access log.

Is this a known bug? Or maybe I have some misconfiguration in my log4j.xml?

Thanks!

Joan.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a new bug. Can you raise this on the log4j2 Jira issue tracker?

The log4j logic for rollover is trying to do the right thing: calculate the next rollover time, subtract one unit (your rollover pattern is `${sys:log.dir}vproxy_access.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}`, so that would be subtract one day), and roll over if the event timestamp is larger than the result. Your result indicates this may not work as intended.

Comment: Ok Remko. Sorry for this delay, I was travelling. I'll open this issue today. Thanks.